# how do I get variables used by a tensorflow layer?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to do gradient descent for a subset of variables only. I know that I can pass in a var_list to the optimizer, however, how do I get the variables from my graph? For example, I have several `tf.layers.dense` layers in a feed-forward network and would like to get those from a specific layer.